# Combinatorial interpretation of a sum with Stirling numbers

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers, combinatorial-proofs

$$\sum_{i,j}{n\brack i+j}\binom{i+j}i$$
Does this have a combinatorial interpretation? I don't see how to use Stirling numbers of the first kind in interpretations. I know that the answer is $(n+1)!$ , but the original question didn't provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about a direct combinatorial proof, but the solution can be easily obtained by taking $k=i+j$ and using the known formula $\sum_{k} \genfrac[]{0pt}{}{n}{k} x^k = x^{\overline{n}}$, where $x^{\overline{n}}$ denotes the rising factorial.

$$\sum_{i,j} \genfrac[]{0pt}{}{n}{i+j} \binom{i+j}{i} = \sum_{k} \genfrac[]{0pt}{}{n}{k} \sum_{i} \binom{k}{i} = \sum_{k} \genfrac[]{0pt}{}{n}{k} 2^k = 2^{\overline{n}} = (n+1)!$$

Comment: I don't think that last step works.  In general, $2^n$ is not equal to $(n+1)!$.

Comment: It's a rising factorial: $2^{\overline{n}} = 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n+1)$.

Comment: You're right, and that clears up my confusion for why nobody pointed it out earlier!  I'll leave my comment in here in case someone else misreads it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a combinatorial proof.  Both sides count the number of ways to partition $n$ numbers into two ordered lists, a first list and a second list.

For the left side, $\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{n}{i+j}$ partitions the $n$ numbers into $i+j$ disjoint cycles.  Then $\binom{i+j}{i}$ chooses $i$ of these cycles.  Since a permutation can be uniquely expressed as a set of disjoint cycles, this creates the first ordered list from the numbers in the $i$ cycles chosen.  Similarly, the leftover $j$ cycles form the second ordered list from the rest of the $n$ numbers.  Summing over all possible values of $i$ and $j$ gives the number of ways to partition the $n$ numbers into a first ordered list and a second ordered list.

For the right side, add a new symbol the the $n$ numbers, like *.  Then create a permutation on these $n+1$ symbols.  This can be done in $(n+1)!$ ways.  The * symbol separates the first ordered list from the second ordered list.